# how to change text color of a id inside class

Tags: html, css, styles, web-deployment, textcolor

I wrote a code and i created id inside class and when im trying to apply css properties on that I'd some of the properties are not working what is the problem.here is my css code

```
    #multiple{
        display:inline-block;
        background-color:black;
        border: 10px solid black;
        color:red;
        font-size:30;
        
    }
```

Comment: Make a fully working code example including your HTML and additional CSS.

Comment: which one is not work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have linked the css file to your html file

Answer (score 0):

You can't create id inside class. If you create id then use `id="idName"` and define your css as `#idName{ your css code }`. And if you create class then use `class="className"` and define your css as `.className{ your css code here }`.